# Mongoid - save and update_attribute does not persist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid3

I am trying to update an attribute from a record in my Mongo collection, but the new value isn't being saved.

```
a = GraphEngine::UserPlace.where(place_id:5000000701039).first
a.place_id = 5000000257690
a.save!
=> true
```

If I inspect `a`, the `place_id` reflects the new value, `5000000257690`, but when I load the record again, the new place_id does not persist.

**Any idea why this is the case?** I've checked to make sure that there isn't a duplicate record.

I've also tried `a.update_attribute(:place_id,5000000257690)` but no luck either. It returns `=> true`, but the value does not persist.

Comment: It seems to be a too big int, no? Have you tried with smaller ids?

Comment: @MrYoshiji Does it matter if type is bigint? I was able to create the object with a bigint value initially.

Comment: Mongo treats bigint and tinyint all as integers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check if place_id is accessible. If not add something like this to the model:

```
attr_accessible :place_id
```

Comment: Thanks, silly mistake. Evidently, mongo will still return true even if mass assignment is not allowed for the attribute.